# query in c# returns false after getting values from the db

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I need to return true if this query returns value, (and it has values in the db)

```
 SELECT * from AllMembers a 
    join Cards c on c.IDMember = a.MemberID
    where LEN(a.EmployeeNum) = 9
    and LEFT(c.CardNumber,3) = '777'
    and a.Email is not null
    and a.LastUpdate > DATEADD(YEAR, -1 , GETDATE())
    and c.CardStatus = 1
    and c.AddedTime  > DATEADD(YEAR, -1 , GETDATE())
    or 
     LEN(a.EmployeeNum) = 9
    and LEFT(c.CardNumber,4) = '2010'
    and a.Email is not null
    and a.LastUpdate > DATEADD(YEAR, -1 , GETDATE())
    and c.CardStatus = 1
    and c.AddedTime  > DATEADD(YEAR, -1 , GETDATE())
```

but writing this value return false, why?

```
 string Query= string.Format(@"use Knowledge4All 
                                    IF EXISTS (
                                                SELECT ID FROM {0}..AllMembers 
                                                JOIN Cards where  IDMember = @memberID
                                                and (where LEN(EmployeeNum) = 9
                                                and LEFT(CardNumber,3) = '777'
                                                and Email is not null
                                                and LastUpdate > DATEADD(YEAR, -1 , GETDATE())
                                                and CardStatus = 1
                                                and AddedTime  > DATEADD(YEAR, -1 , GETDATE())))
                                                 select 1
                                                 OR
                                                 IF exists(
                                                (LEN(EmployeeNum) = 9
                                                and LEFT(CardNumber,4) = '2010'
                                                and Email is not null
                                                and LastUpdate > DATEADD(YEAR, -1 , GETDATE())
                                                and CardStatus = 1
                                                and AddedTime  > DATEADD(YEAR, -1 , GETDATE()) )
                                                SELECT 1", DbName);
```

Am I writing this wrong? what is the best why to rum this ?

Comment: Why do you add _use KnowledgeAll_ at the beginning of the query? Are you connected to a different database?

Comment: @Steve right, its a mistake

Comment: i think that your problem is here `{0}..AllMembers` you have too many dots(.), should `{0}.AllMembers`

Comment: @styx that syntax is used to pick the default schema. For instance, if the default schema is dbo then that would be equivalent to <tablename>.dbo.AllMembers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your query like following.

```
 IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 from AllMembers a 
    join Cards c on c.IDMember = a.MemberID
    where LEN(a.EmployeeNum) = 9
    and LEFT(c.CardNumber,3) = '777'
    and a.Email is not null
    and a.LastUpdate > DATEADD(YEAR, -1 , GETDATE())
    and c.CardStatus = 1
    and c.AddedTime  > DATEADD(YEAR, -1 , GETDATE())
    or 
     LEN(a.EmployeeNum) = 9
    and LEFT(c.CardNumber,4) = '2010'
    and a.Email is not null
    and a.LastUpdate > DATEADD(YEAR, -1 , GETDATE())
    and c.CardStatus = 1
    and c.AddedTime  > DATEADD(YEAR, -1 , GETDATE())
    )
    BEGIN
     SELECT 1 as Status
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
     SELECT 0 AS Status
    END
```

If you are using `ExecuteScalar()`, you will get the appropriate value.

Other observation in your query

1- USE statement is not required. It is only required if connection string is set to a different default catalog.

2- You are using `string.format` without replacing anything.

> but writing this value return false, why?

It may be due to the condition are not matching with any of the record in your table. Run the query directly in SSMS and check the output.

Comment: `USE` might be required if connection string is set to a different default catalog.